# Formatting date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, frontend, momentjs

I have a date like this `2021-10-20T07:03:02-04:00` and from this date I need to make date like this: `Wednesday 7:03am`

My try:

```
moment(date).format('dddd h:mma');
```

But I get `Wednesday 14:03am`.
Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `moment().format('dddd hh:mm a');` try this is working fine for me

Comment: It should work correctly. Which version of moment.js library are you using?

Comment: I think problem on ```-04:00``` in the end of date. Cause it's works fine without this

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in momentjs docs
you can do it like this

```
moment(someday).format('dddd HH:MM a');
```

[moments docs >>](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: `HH` gives 24h format.

Answer (score -3):

This should work fine, the problem is that your initial date is in wrong format.

```
moment(date).format('dddd hh:mm a');
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and explain what exactly you changed and why it works.